# why to declare delegate with event i, I don't see the use of the keyword event?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Please show me simple example why do we need it and what will happen if we didn't use it in the example with delegate.
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we need the "event" keyword while defining events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028724/why-do-we-need-the-event-keyword-while-defining-events)

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett oh you managed to find sense out of this question. Kudos.

Comment: are you asking for the difference between the event and the delegate keyword?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: I think he wants an example (like in Jon's answer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure:

```
// With events...
public class Button
{
    public event EventHandler Click;
}

public void Client
{
    public void Method(Button button)
    {
        // This is all I can do...
        button.Click += SomeHandler;
    }
}


// With plain delegate fields or properties...
public class Button
{
    public EventHandler Click { get; set; }
}

public void Client
{
    public void Method(Button button)
    {
        // Who cares if someone else is already subscribed...
        button.Click = SomeHandler;

        // And let's just raise the event ourselves...
        button.Click(button, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

In other words, with events you've got a *controlled* implementation of the pub/sub pattern - separate subscribers can't interfere with each other (except perhaps by throwing an exception within their handler) and only the publisher can "publish" (call the handlers).