# event EventHandler vs EventHandler

Tags: c#, event-handling

In C# Is there a fundamental difference between using

`event EventHandler<myeventargs>` and 
`EventHandler<myeventargs>` 
As they both produce the same effect from what I can see apart from using the event keyword gives you a different icon in intellisense.

Comment: possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028724/why-do-we-need-the-event-keyword-while-defining-events

Comment: There is, same difference as between a field and a property.  If you don't use the *event* keyword and expose the delegate object directly then any code can do nasty things like setting it back to null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They seems to be alike, but really different.

With `event` keyword, you are making them something like properties, which means you can **register them in public, while maintain a private back-end**.

However, without `event` keyword, it's just a public delegate field, and anyone can remove or modify others' events, which is a "[encapsulation disaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028724/why-do-we-need-the-event-keyword-while-defining-events)" as @Jonskeet said.

Check this [article](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/events.html) by Jon Skeet, it's very helpful :)

**Edit**:

What I summarized above was not my original thinking, all credits to @Jonskeet's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028724/why-do-we-need-the-event-keyword-while-defining-events).

Comment: Why don't you just provide the link of another post that mentions about [encapsulation disaster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028724/why-do-we-need-the-event-keyword-while-defining-events) ?

Comment: I thought a brief summary is better a dull link, but it's my fault not to put the link in.