# Where is the line between a traditional event and a simple delegate assignment?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I've been playing around with anonymous functions and delegates. It's left me wondering what advantages the traditional ways of declaring events have.

Consider this inside of a class.

```
public delegate void MyHandler(string input);
public MyHandler OnSomethingHappens;

// ...then, somewhere else
OnSomethingHappens("The thing that happened...");
```

From outside the method...

```
MyClass.OnSomethingHappens += (input) => { Console.WriteLine("Do something"; };
MyClass.OnSomethingHappens += (input) => { Console.WriteLine("Do something else"; };
```

How is this any different than a traditional event handling situation, where I code up a `SomethingHappensEventArgs` class, wire it to an actual event, etc.?

With the code above, I am able to assign code to execute when the class says something has happened...which is essentially what an event does.

Why would I go to all the trouble of creating a "true" event?  Dare I say it...Intellisense icons?  :-)

Comment: Mainly so others can't clear out everyone wired up to the event already - [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028724/why-do-we-need-the-event-keyword-while-defining-events)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your approach, any object can clear the delegate:

```
MyClass.OnSomethingHappens = null;
```

or invoke it:

```
MyClass.OnSomethingHappens();
```

Events only allow other objects to add/remove delegates.

Answer (score -1):

if you declare `OnSomethingHappens` as public event

```
public MyHandler OnSomethingHappens;
```

you'll be able to do only the `+=` and `-=` opertors
if you keep it public you can assign it null from outside the class